# How can a user can execute my NFC code without downloading my App?

Tags: android, nfc

How can a user execute my NFC code without downloading my app?

The following code works so long as I have my app installed. However, in the real world, a user won't have my app installed. Rather I just want this code to execute just by scanning a Passive NFC tag. Code follows:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if(intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG))

    {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NfcIntent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        sms.sendTextMessage("5555555555", null, "Hello Folks", null, null);
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage("Hi! I am tag #1");  
        writeNdefMessage(tag,ndefMessage);

    }

}
```

I'm just trying to send a text message from the user's phone to a predetermined number with a hard-coded message...thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You can't execute code without the app. it is like trying to run without legs

Comment: Have you tried to store your message as a SMS NFC message? E.g. the app TagWriter allows to create tags in that format. Such a tag should be recognized by any NFC capable phone without additional app. However it may require a few taps to confirm the SMS sending.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a user execute my NFC code without downloading my app?

The code cannot be executed without the app.

> The following code works so long as I have my app installed. However, in the real world, a user won't have my app installed.

Taken from [this website](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/nfc-tag1.htm):

"*NFC tags are passive, meaning they don't have any power source. Instead, they literally draw power from the device that reads them, thanks to magnetic induction. When a reader gets close enough to a tag, it energizes it and transfer data from that tag.*"

This means they transfer data - they cannot execute code. You can transfer code, but the code will not do anything. The exception is if you have a custom app to recieve code to then execute it - but who has an app like that installed with their phone?

---

From [this website](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/what-is-nfc-how-nfc-works-what-it-does-3472879/):

"*At the time of writing the NFC standard has three modes of operation: the peer-to-peer mode that lets two smartphones swap data, a read/write mode in which one active device picks up info from a passive one, and card emulation, in which an NFC device such as a smartphone can be used like a contactless credit card.*"

This means that as of now, the action you described:

> Rather I just want this code to execute just by scanning a Passive NFC tag.

Is not possible without custom software. Which again means - the user has to install your app. and then the point is lost. In addition, I don't think they will open to code being executed by NFC tags, as it creates a massive security vounerability.

---

So as of writing, you have to promt the second user to install the app for it to work(if phone to phone transfers is what you are trying to do).